# User friendly messages from model level validation

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I'm currently working on a JSF 2 application (with primefaces) running on glassfish.
Our datamodel is a standard (AIXM), so we cannot modify it. Validation rules are defined on the model.

In our application, the guis do not exaclty reflect the model. 
For example, some of the fields from the model are not displayed (they are calculated from the user input).
The model also has a ConditionCombination class that allows to express logical relations between lists of objects. 
In our application, we only use 2 of these lists of objects.
So we compute some attributes of the ConditionCombination.

Since we have cross field validations (which seems to be difficult to do using JSF validation mechanisms), we chose to do the validation at the model level.
But some of the error messages do not make sense to the user.
For example, some error messages are on fields that are not displayed to the user.

Are there any ideas on how to improve this validation? 
(Or should we implement it at the JSF level instead and rewrite all the validation rules from a model perspective to a view perspective)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();           context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Your message here", null));`

Just write your code in model and append above code for custom messages.

Comment: Yes, this is how we display the validation errors that we have found on the model. But our problem is that the content of some messages is not clear for the user (some refer to attributes that are in the model but not in the gui).